# How do you sum the individual elements of a pair in a list?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Im trying to take the first and second element of the pair from a list so they can be summed. Here is my code, I am not sure why it is giving an error

```
func :: [(Double,Double)] -> (Double,Double)
func [(x, y)] = map fst (x,y)
```

Comment: You've defined the function using a pattern that only matches a list consisting of a *single* pair (consisting of the values `x` and `y`). I think you mean `func xs = map fst xs` (where `xs` is the conventional way to refer to a list) - but this isn't right either, and won't compile (because it produces a `[Double]` result). `map` always produces a list - you will probably need `map` as part of the solution but the final result can't be a call to `map`.

Comment: What's the error? Have you looked at it?

Comment: write down a few examples then you'll see the pattern. you need to accumulate the first and the second element of each pair in the list. You can use [foldr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) to accumulate values or use [unzip](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:unzip).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, let's take your current, non-working definition:

```
func :: [(Double,Double)] -> (Double,Double)
func [(x, y)] = map fst (x,y)
```

This has several things wrong with it:

- Your pattern match `[(x, y)]` only matches a list with exactly one element. Any list with 2 or more elements will cause an error since they do not match.
- `map` cannot be applied to tuples; it can only be applied to lists.
- Even if you could `map` over a tuple, `fst` must be applied to a tuple directly - `fst (a, b)` gives `a`, while `map fst (a, b)` doesn't make sense.

Let's look at some alternate definitions.

## List comprehension

```
func_1 :: [(Double,Double)] -> (Double,Double)
func_1 list =
    let fsts = [ a | (a, _) <- list ]
        snds = [ b | (_, b) <- list ]
    in (sum fsts, sum snds)
```

This separately extracts each first element from the list, then each second element from the list, then adds them together.

## Mapping

```
func_2 :: [(Double,Double)] -> (Double,Double)
func_2 list =
    let fsts = map fst list
        snds = map snd list
    in (sum fsts, sum snds)
```

Maps `fst` over each element of the input list to get a list of all first elements of the list. Then maps `snd` to do the same for second elements.

## Recursion

```
func_3 :: [(Double,Double)] -> (Double,Double)
func_3 [] = (0, 0)
func_3 ((a,b) : xs) =
    let (a', b') = func_3 xs
    in (a+a', b+b')
```

A bit of a different approach. Lists in Haskell are formed recursively: `[a, b, c]` is equivalent to `(a : (b : (c : [])))`. This means we can use pattern matching to get the first element of the list as well as all the other elements of the list. This definition works in two parts:

- If the list has no elements, just return `(0, 0)` (the *base case*).
- If the list has at least one element, take the rest of the list (e.g. `[b, c]` if `[a, b, c]` was given, or `[]` if `[a]` was given), calculate its sum using `func_3` again, then add the first element back on.

Comment: To bradrn's very fine answer I would add `funct_4 = foldr (\(a,b) (aa, bb) -> (a+aa, b+bb)) (0,0)`  Summation over a list is the classic example of where to use `fold`.

Comment: `unzip` is another option: `let (fsts, snds) = unzip list in (sum fsts, sum snds)`

Comment: @JohnF.Miller I did consider adding an example of `foldr` - and this is indeed a classic sample - but I thought `foldr` may be a bit confusing for a beginner. I probably should have added it for completeness.

Comment: @4castle Or more concise one `bimap sum sum (unzip list)` with `Data.Bifunctor` imported. Anyway, `let ... in` expression is clear enough.