# How do I find the Average of a List of Coordinate Tuples in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

How do I add a list of tuples in Haskell which represent x and y coordinates and then find the average of all the x values and y values (basically trying to find a centroid).

So lets say I had an input list of [(1,1),(2,2),(3,6)] and I want the output to be (2,3).

Comment: Is the answer to this question enough to get you started? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013159/how-do-you-sum-the-individual-elements-of-a-pair-in-a-list

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Just got back to this, so couldn't reply for a while!

Answer (score 0):

This will work without a space leak and without breaking stream fusion:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import Data.Foldable (foldl')

centroid :: (Fractional n, Foldable t) => t (n, n) -> (n, n)
centroid coords = (xsum/count, ysum/count)
 where (xsum,ysum,count) = foldl' go (0,0,0) coords
       go (!xs,!ys,!c) (x,y) = (xs + x, ys + y, c + 1)
```

Feel free to replace / with `div` and Fractional with Integral if you want, and/or add realToFrac if necessary to make your types work out. Also, if you don't want to use BangPatterns, you can use seq on all three elements instead.